# Kernel level memory handling coding

Tags: c, linux-kernel

My requirement is to store data in kernel..Data are incoming packets from networks..which may be different in size and have to store for example 250ms duration..and there should be 5 such candidate for which kernel level memory management is required..since packets are coming very fast..my approach is to allocate a large memory say 2mb memory for each such candidate..bez kmalloc and kfree have timing overhead..any help regarding that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.. Your question is.. "is there a problem using a kernel memory pool"?

Comment: My requirement is as follow..I need to handle a situation in linux kernel level..where packets(TCP/IP) from networks are coming at a rate 1mbps..I need to store the packets for example 250ms..and packet size may be different..As kmalloc and kfree need some time to do..I need a large memory block for example 2mb..which will be allocated once and never free till I need..Is it possible to do in Linux kernel

Comment: These are typically handled with **scatter-gather** which is supported by `skbufs` afaik.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But I think my requirement is to buffer the incoming packets using one shot memory allocation done by kmalloc for some duration.

Comment: @kernelCoder: Are you sure data is coming in at a rate of 1 mbps? 1 million bits per second seems very slow for ethernet, and only works out to a maximum of (slightly less than) 32 KiB of data every 250 ms (with a worst case of 488 "minimum size" packets every 250 ms).

Comment: @Brendan: No I am wrong..sry for that..My intention was high data rate like in LTE..In that case do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[`sk_buff`s](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/skbuff.h) are a generic answer that is network related or as [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348709/mike) points out a [kernel memory cache](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/slab.h) is even more generic answer to your question. However, I believe you may have [put a solution before the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The bottle neck with LTE/HSDPA/GSM is the driver and how you get data from the device to the CPU. This depends on how hardware is connected. Are you using SPI, UART, SDHC, USB, PCI?

Also, at least with HSDPA, you need a `ppp` connection. Isn't LTE the same? Ethernet is not the model to use in this case. Typically you need to emulate a high speed tty. Also, [n_gsm](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/tty/n_gsm.c) supplies a network interface; I am not entirely familiar with this interface, but I suspect that this is to support `LTE`. This is not well [documented](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/serial/n_gsm.txt).  Also, there is the [Option](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/option.c) USB serial driver, if this is the hardware you are using. [An example patch](http://lists.ofono.org/pipermail/ofono/2011-February/008837.html) using `n_gsm` to handle LTE; I believe this patch was reworked into the current `n_gsm` network support.

You need to tell us more about your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted within the comments:

`struct sk_buff`, and it is created for that exact specific purpose

see for example http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/skbuff